# Is it possible to retrieve if a Youtube video is live?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api

I just want to know if is it possible to get that somehow this information through API calls (server-side calls) to the YouTube API. I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: When you say "live", are you talking about live-streaming videos or videos that are processed and viewable on YT?

Comment: Videos that are Hangouts on Air. I've found a way to figure it out. I will post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out:

The `result.snippet` contains a key called `tags` that contains 3 tags when it's a Hangout on Air (#hoa, #HangoutOnAir and something else). That way I can differ it from a HOA.